# how to solve this :The URI prefix is not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

When I am going to add some website like `http://www.nirmauni.ac.in/`, then it says the above mentioned error. So, how to fix this problem?
I have given my code. Just go through and say where the change should be made.

```
bool IsLinkWorking(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    //You can set some parameters in the "request" object...
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return true;
    }
    catch
    { 
        //TODO: Check for the right exception here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide minimal repro. Avoid copy-paste wall of code from your previous question/source code.

Comment: @Alexei LevenKov bro i have edit the code,here servicepont.....not working

Comment: Your edit still does not provide a repro as you can see from your comments to Sachin's (+1) answer - really just one line would be enough with all constant inline in the sample.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Your Error It seems that you are creating a web request with wrong url.

Please make sure that in `(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);` url string must start with proper protocol like (http,https etc.)

Comment: @hitarth can u give me the any value of textBox that you checked for non-working example.?

Comment: @hitarth which protocol nirmauni.ac.in supports? you need to add accordingly protocol. like this http://www.nirmauni.ac.in (in case of http protocol). your url parameter ultimately must have some protocol to create valid request.

Comment: hey it is checking this url "javascript:go();" so it happens? and yes you are right i got you but how it can be done so "your url parameter ultimately must have some protocol to create valid request"

Comment: it's all depends on you. either you can do is, "don't allow user to enter Url without http or any other protocol(by using Url validation) or you can just check the user input and accordingly add to user input and before passing it to WebRequest.Create(url) function

Comment: yes i got you ,but here i have entered the url proper only but string checkes or webrequest is gone to "javascript:go();" is their any solution  to passes this href

Comment: I guess `go()` is your javascript function. So if you want to pass then just change the function like this `go(url)` and pass url value from wherever you are calling this method. Hopefully you got it and please mark my solution as answer.:)

Comment: Saved !! Cheers !!